# Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/Release ubuntu 13.04

Tags: updates

I have some errors while run `sudo apt-get update`. How do I solve this ? Thank you.

```
W: A error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://extras.ubuntu.com raring Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 16126D3A3E5C1192 Ubuntu Extras Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/Release  
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 0):

**ADD http:// on the linksXD** *(they don let me put links)*

The repositories are continuously updating their signatures, so the signatures you have are no longer valid. It could also be that that link does not longer exist.  This is easy to repare it:

**This first part is a personal suggestion**

1.- Recreate your repositories

There is a very good page that generates you a clean source list that solve you many errors

repogen.simplylinux.ch/index.php

This generator, creates you a sorce list and the comands to give you the keys.
Of course after  *apt-get update*  there are going to be errors like the one that have been given to you.

**This one solve your problem**

To get the updated keys you have to enter this page

keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371/

you put  0x followed only the numbers keys:

0x16126D3A3E5C1192

Then it will get you the updated link of the GPG keys, enter the one at the top. Then it will give you a gpg link like this:

sites.google.com/site/imageneswada/_/rsrc/1271717061232/home/Public%20Key%20Server%20--%20Get%20%60%600x6af0e1940624a220%20%27%27%20-%20Mozilla%20Firefox_003.png

After that you copy the link and add it to a command like this:

wget -q "*web link*" -O- | sudo apt-key add -

And you will have added you gpg key

Comment: But it still the same. sidratul@tree:~$ wget -q "http://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x16126D3A3E5C1192" -O- | sudo apt-key add -
OK